# Non-frozen collections are not allowed inside collections: set<schema.myTable>

Tags: java, hibernate, cassandra

I am unable to figure out how to resolve this compilation error. Currently not able to use the Frozen/FrozenValue annotation. I need to find a way to declare the UDT class in the Pojoclass as a valid marker to be used. FYI.. The "myTable" table is declared as Frozen within the cassandra schema.

POJO class

```
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.cassandra.core.PrimaryKeyType;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Set;

@Data
@Table(value = "MainTable")
public class Data{

@Column(value = "myTable")
public Set<UDTClass> myTableDTO;
}
```

UDT  class

```
@Data
@UserDefinedType("myTable")
public class UDTClass{

public String someData;
```

I am using the springframework package for Cassandra mapping.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how it works in Spring, but I think it should be like this:

1. add codec in MappingManager of Cassandra:

```
    manager.udtCodec(UDTClass.class);
```

2. create type in cql:

```
    CREATE TYPE IF NOT EXISTS myTable (someData text);
```

3. mark type as frozen in the set in the table:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MainTable (innerTable set<frozen\<myTable\>>);
```